# VBA Excel click on href and fill in form

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to get some data from a website by using vba.
The data i want is from this site: https://www.uitvoeringarbeidsvoorwaardenwetgeving.nl/mozard/!suite16.scherm1168?mSel=145576

What i want the code to do is click on the purple bar with the pencil 
on it so the screen appears for filters and than fill in a specific time frame in the filters. 
When this is done i want to get the data that appears.

Im able to navigate to the site and click on the purple bar so the filter screen appears. but i cant fill in the dates 
this is the code i have so far:

```
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim pastDate As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim futuredate As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.uitvoeringarbeidsvoorwaardenwetgeving.nl/mozard/!suite16.scherm1168?mGmr=66"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

Set HTMLAs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each HTMLA In HTMLAs
    'Debug.Print HTMLA.className, HTMLA.getAttribute("href"), HTMLA.getAttribute("rel"), HTMLA.innerText

    If HTMLA.getAttribute("href") = "https://www.uitvoeringarbeidsvoorwaardenwetgeving.nl/mozard/!suite16.scherm1168?mGmr=66#editmodal" Then
    HTMLA.Click
    Exit For
    End If

Next HTMLA
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy:
DoEvents: Loop

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("frm_FKMT_B931_542_823883_dva_id1")
HTMLInput.Value = "01-01-2020" 'THIS GIVES AN ERROR?
```

The last line of code gives an error and i dont understand why??

This is the HTML code from the website that i want to change the value of:

```
<input name="FKMT_B931_542_823883_dva" class="datumveld form-control" id="frm_FKMT_B931_542_823883_dva_id1" type="text" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}">
```

Thanks and sorry for the inconvience or poorly asked question, if there is anything else you guys need to now please feel free to ask!

Thank you!!

Comment: It's simple the first a tag: `Set e = IE.document.getElementByID("tabel2").GetElementsByTagName("a")(0)` The next line is only the click on the separated element: `e.Click`

Comment: Thanks! i figured out the clicking part, now i cant fill in the value i want in the startdate eventhough it is set as an input and i can get the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example to fill the first date field. The IDs seems not very stable.
**Beware:** There is a pattern for the entered dates
`pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).(0[1-9]|1[012]).[0-9]{4}"`

There are some html events. I don't know if it is necessary to trigger them to make the dialog realy work.

Have you checked if the page works in IE?

```
Sub OpenAndFillForm()

Dim browser As Object
Dim url As String
Dim nodeToClick As Object
Dim nodeForm As Object
Dim nodeFirstDate As Object

  url = "https://www.uitvoeringarbeidsvoorwaardenwetgeving.nl/mozard/!suite16.scherm1168?mGmr=66"

  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = True
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  Set nodeToClick = browser.document.getElementByID("tabel2").getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
  nodeToClick.Click
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

  Set nodeForm = browser.document.getElementByID("tabel12")
  Set nodeFirstDate = nodeForm.getElementsByClassName("datumveld")(0)
  nodeFirstDate.Value = "31-12-2019"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Im going to try and check if it works! the page works in IE!

Comment: Your code worked! but i dont understand why my code didnt work? with the value can you explain it to me?

Comment: It's like I said *The IDs seems not very stable*. This is the ID from your Code `frm_FKMT_B931_542_823883_dva_id1` and this is the ID from the same element in "my" html code `frm_FKMT_B931_542_823497_dva_id1`. They are different, because the server generates them individual. So you can't use them to identify elements. Every time you see "cryptic like" names for IDs oder css clases, dont trust in.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! i did not understand at first what you meant with the IDs are not stable, but now i do!:) Thanks for your help! if i have any further questions can I ask them to you please

Comment: @T.M. Thanks! im new to this so thanks for your help!:) I have another question tho, im getting data from the site but the site updates the data when you scroll down so i need to scroll down wait and scroll down wait and then get the data, does anyone now how to do this dynamic

Comment: @RasM10 Suggest to discuss this at [Stack Overflow Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)